# Making an array where each has it's own value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, variables

How would I assign Cat, dog and Bear it's own value. So it says i.e. Bear = 50. or cat36 ?

HTML:

```
<p id="item"> </p>
<p id="valueOfItem"> </p>
```

Javascript:

```
var items = ["cat","dog","Bear"]
```

I can't find a single way assign cat, dog and bear a seperate value and then output it.

Comment: Do you want the output to be in HTML? Are you looking for a Javascript answer that generates HTML?

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for an object (denoted with curly braces `{}`), not an array:

```
var items = {bear: 50, cat: 36, dog: 13};
console.log(items.cat);
//36
```

Answer (score 1):

The [solution by @nvioli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41352543/535871) is good, but has the disadvantage that it loses the ordering of the items. Here's a couple of other approaches, both of which preserve the item order. First, an array of objects:

```
var items = [
    { name: "cat", value: 36 },
    { name: "dog", value: 13 },
    { name: "Bear", value: 50 }
];
```

The second is parallel arrays:

```
var items = ["cat","dog","Bear"];
var values = [36, 13, 50];
```

The latter is more difficult code to write and maintain because related items are stored in separate arrays. But this structure occasionally has its uses.

Comment: Of course, if ordering is not important, the other answer is better.

Comment: @Barmar - Not necessarily. Iterating through an array is a bit simpler than iterating through all of an object's properties. Plus you automatically get a count of how many items you're dealing with via the array's `length` property. On the other hand, if you have to look up a value by item name, then the other solution is definitely better.